# Automatically set value of a managed bean variable with JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, managed-bean

I would like to pass an value to a managed bean under the hood. So I have this managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mbWorkOrderController")
@SessionScoped
public class WorkOrderController {

    // more attributes...

    private WorkOrder workOrderCurrent;

    // more code here...

    public WorkOrder getWorkOrderCurrent() {
        return workOrderCurrent;
    }

    public void setWorkOrderCurrent(WorkOrder workOrderCurrent) {
        this.workOrderCurrent = workOrderCurrent;
    }
}
```

It holds a parameter `workOrderCurrent` of the custom type `WorkOrder`. The class `WorkOrder` has an attribute `applicant` of type `String`.

At the moment I am using a `placeholder` inside my `inputtext` to show the user, what he needs to type inside an `inputText`.

```
<p:inputText id="applicant"
    value="#{mbWorkOrderController.workOrderCurrent.applicant}"
    required="true" maxlength="6"
    placeholder="#{mbUserController.userLoggedIn.username}" />
```

What I want to do, is to automatically pass the value of `mbUserController.userLoggedIn.username` to `mbWorkOrderController.workOrderCurrent.applicant` and remove the `inputText` for `applicant` completely from my form.

I tried to use `c:set`:

```
<c:set value="#{mbUserController.userLoggedIn.username}" target="#{mbWorkOrderController}" property="workOrderCurrent.applicant" />
```

But unfortunatelly I get a `javax.servlet.ServletException` with the message:

*The class 'WorkOrderController' does not have the property 'workOrderCurrent.applicant'.*

Does anybody have an advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *The class 'WorkOrderController' does not have the property 'workOrderCurrent.applicant'.*

Your `<c:set>` syntax is incorrect.

> ```
> <c:set value="#{mbUserController.userLoggedIn.username}"
>        target="#{mbWorkOrderController}" 
>        property="workOrderCurrent.applicant" />
> ```

You seem to be thinking that the part..

```
value="#{mbWorkOrderController.workOrderCurrent.applicant}"
```

..works under the covers as below:

```
WorkOrderCurrent workOrderCurrent = mbWorkOrderController.getWorkOrderCurrent();
workOrderCurrent.setApplicant(applicant);
mbWorkOrderController.setWorkOrderCurrent(workOrderCurrent);
```

This isn't true. It works under the covers as below:

```
mbWorkOrderController.getWorkOrderCurrent().setApplicant(applicant);
```

The correct `<c:set>` syntax is therefore as below:

```
<c:set value="#{mbUserController.userLoggedIn.username}"
       target="#{mbWorkOrderController.workOrderCurrent}" 
       property="applicant" />
```

That said, all of this isn't the correct solution to [the concrete problem you actually tried to solve](http://xyproblem.info). You should perform model prepopulating in the model itself. This can be achieved by using `@ManagedProperty` to reference another bean property and by using `@PostConstruct` to perform initialization based on it.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mbWorkOrderController")
@SessionScoped
public class WorkOrderController {

    @ManagedProperty("#{mbUserController.userLoggedIn}")
    private User userLoggedIn;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        workOrderCurrent.setApplicant(userLoggedIn.getUsername());
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the extensive post! This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could explain the context a bit more, but here's another solution. If you're navigating from another page, you can pass some identifier of work WorkOrder in the URL, like this `http://host:port/context/page.xhtml?workOrderId=1`.

Then, you can set the identifier in the managed bean like this:

```
<h:html>
    <f:viewParam name="workOrderId" value="#{mbWorkOrderController.id}"/>
</h:html>
```

You'll have to add a new property to your bean:

```
public class WorkOrderController {
    private long id;
    public long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

    // ...
}
```

And then, after the property has been set by JSF, you can find the work order in a lifecycle event:

```
<h:html>
    <f:viewParam name="workOrderId" value="#{mbWorkOrderController.id}"/>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{mbWorkOrderController.findWorkOrder()}"/>
</h:html>

public class WorkOrderController {
    private long id;
    public long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

    public void findWorkOrder() {
        this.workOrderCurrent = null /* some way of finding the work order */
    }

    // ...
}
```

This strategy has the advantage of letting you have bookmarkable URLs.